# can you develop for ios by connecting an ios device on windows by using expo

Tags: ios, reactjs, windows, react-native, mobile

I know there are similar topics like this but as the title indicates, would you be able to develop an app for iOS using expo with a real iphone device connected to the same LAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, For expo you don't require xcode or android studio. you need to install expo on your iPhone and connect to the same network and scan the QR code. sometimes it does not work on LAN try switching to tunnel for better connectivity.

For iOS you can use

> Send Link With email option

This will email you a link, click it from your Mail app, and it’s running on your device!